# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type JpaVendorAdapter found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-bean

I'm trying to setup Java-based hibernate in memory database and start using it from a test, but when Hibernate beans are loaded Application context fail with. The point if this exercise is to setup simple service with CRUD operations using CrudRepository for a few classes and WRITE

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 72 more`

Related configuration and source code:

**hibernate.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:press
jdbc.username = user
jdbc.password = 
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

**HibernateConfig.java** - which fails to load

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("net.agilob.press.entity");
        return lef.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "net.agilob.press.entity" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("create-drop"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java** - file loaded as configuration for test

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.agilob.press.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "net.agilob.press.entity.repository")
@Import(HibernateConfig.class)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PostService getPostService() {
        return new PostService();
    }
}
```

**PostServiceTest.java** - this one should create instance(s) of Post, save it in memory database and extract later (just to see it works):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional
public class PostDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setContent("body");
        post.setDescription("description");
        post.setIntroduction("introduction");
        post.setTitle("title");
        post.setTitleBrowser("title browser");
        postRepository.save(post);
    }

    @Test
    public void testList() {
        // checks if spring wiring was correct
        assertNotNull("Problem with spring beans", postRepository);
        assertFalse(postRepository.findTop10ByTitleOrderByIdAsc().isEmpty());
    }
}
```

**PostService:**

```
@Service("postService")
@Transactional
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

...
}
```

**PostRepository:**

```
public interface PostRepository extends BaseRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

I tried to create one more @Beans annotated method in HibernateConfig that was bulding JpaVendorAdapter instance but when I run the test it was failing with:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: Factory method 'createSharedEntityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.initProxyClassLoader(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:199)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.<init>(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:191)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:163)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:120)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 60 more`

my [pom.xml](https://gitlab.com/snippets/25944)

so I think something else is wrong in the setup.

Any help how to design and setup it in a better way very appreciated.

Comment: Have you included hibernate-entitymanager as one of the dependencies in your project??

Comment: @skm question updated with my pom.xml at the bottom, yes I have it.

Comment: While creating bean for entityManagerFactory ,you need to set vendorAdaptor via new HibernateJpaVendorAdaptor() ,are u doing it ?

Comment: @skm thanks, I updated question with my answer, found solution for it thanks to you. If you want, please copy my answer and respond to this question I'll mark it as answer for your benefit :)

Comment: No need for thanks mate. We are all helping each other. Btw i have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your entityManagerFactory to know the provider class as well as jpa dialect, you need to set jpaVendorAdaptor on your entityManagerFactory bean. This can be done as

```
@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(MySQL5Dialect.class.getName());
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}
```

and calling this method inside your entityManagerFactory as follows :

```
lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have all required dependencies?

Is HibernateJpaVendorAdapter available on your classpath?

Try to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is HibernateJpaVendorAdapter available on your classpath? -  yes